# All numbers in Excel showing in scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Whenever I type any number in Excel it turns it into scientific notation.

45 and 67 appear as:

[image]

It does not change even when I change the category to *Number*.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure the cell isn't formatted as scientific. Right click the cell, choose *format cell* and change to *Number* maybe?

Comment: Make the column larger maybe the cell width is too small

Answer (score 0):

It's odd if entering `45` leads to a displayed value of `4.5E-10` (which represents `4.5 * (10^ -10)`, which is actually `0.00000000045`). Even if your cell has been formatted to Scientific, entering 45 should result in a value of `4.5E+01`.

In any case, I would start by formatting the cell(s) in question as Number (with at least 11 decimal places) to confirm what the actual decimal value is. If this results in a value of `45`, then problem solved (although I cannot explain why you were seeing `4.5E-10` before).

If you see a very small decimal value such as 0.00000000045, then I would check whether you have any VBA on the sheet in question which could be altering entered values and perhaps try creating an entirely new workbook to see if you get the same behaviour. If you are finding that on an entirely new/clean workbook (having performed a Clear All on all cells and confirmed there is no VBA in place) that typing `45` into a call results in a displayed value of `4.5E-10`, then I'm stumped! Perhaps you could upload a copy of a workbook with the issue somewhere for us to take a look at?